# Can I use a paramter inside a datatable in Gherkin?

Tags: unit-testing, cucumber, gherkin

Can I do something like this in Cucumber? Using a parameter inside a datatable like this.

I know the example is not the best but what I want is to use previous parameters again and together

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers with <total> 

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left | total       |
    |    12 |   5 |    7 | <eat>+<left>|
    |    20 |   5 |   15 | <eat>+<left>|
```

Comment: I don't think think it is officially supported but Cucumber replaces the table values from left to right. So maybe if you put total in the first column it works.